# Looping to initialize multiple StreamWriters

Tags: c#, loops, file-io, streamwriter

I want to do something like the following:

```
int loopCount = 0;
while (loopCount != 18)
{
    StreamWriter DBSplit + loopCount = 
    new StreamWriter(@"L:\BananaDB\DBFILE" + loopCount + ".txt");
    loopCount++;
}
```

What is the best way to do this? At the moment the problem is `"DBSplit + loopCount"`. While yes it is because I'm trying to add an int to the StreamWriter variable, I cannot use string either. Is there any solution?

Comment: As ever, if you want multiple variables indexed by number, use an array or a list. (If you want multiple variables indexed by name, use a `Dictionary<string, ...>` instead.) There's nothing specific about `StreamWriter` here - other than the fact that you'll need to be careful to dispose of everything.

Comment: IMO, This sounds like a design flaw (saving what I guess is the same data in 18 different places?) and a liability to make sure that the streams are closed correctly

Comment: No, it's not a design flaw. I need to split a large file in to 18 smaller ones.

Comment: I still dont see why all 18 streams need to be open at once.

Comment: My program is reading line by line from a very large file, depending on what information is on that line, it will be written to a particular file. That is why.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why my question deserves -2? What is wrong with it?

Comment: @Mitchell It's not a bad question, bumped you up one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array ? Also you can replace `while` with a `for` loop:

```
var writers = new StreamWriter[18];

for(int i =0; i<18; i++)
    writers[i] = new StreamWriter(@"L:\BananaDB\DBFILE" + i + ".txt");
```

Comment: Thanks, very suitable solution.

Comment: Don't forget to call Dispose()/Close() on each one when you're done with them. Or wrap each one you use in using(){} block, if possible.